# Access denied when attempting to connect to mysql from servlet in myeclipse

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I'm trying to run a simple `servlet/mysql webapp` using tomcat server  in my `eclipse`.
when I try to connect to the `database` from a `servlet`, I get the following error:

```
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create 
PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: YES))
```

below is the script that I executed:

The servlet:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

public class EmployeeServlet extends HttpServlet {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Resource(name = "jdbc/testDB")
    DataSource ds;

  public EmployeeServlet() {
    super();
  }

  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
      Connection con = ds.getConnection();

      Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
      String query = "select * from Employee";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
      response.setContentType("text/html");
      out.print("<center><h1>Employee Details</h1></center>");
      out.print("<html><body>");
      out.print("<table border=\"1\" cellspacing=10 cellpadding=5>");
      out.print("<tr><th>Employee ID</th>");
      out.print("<th>Employee Name</th>");
      out.print("<th>Salary</th>");
      out.print("<th>Department</th></tr>");

      while (rs.next()) {
        out.print("<tr>");
        out.print("<td>" + rs.getInt("emp_id") + "</td>");
        out.print("<td>" + rs.getString("emp_name") + "</td>");
        out.print("<td>" + rs.getDouble("salary") + "</td>");
        out.print("<td>" + rs.getString("dept_name") + "</td>");
        out.print("</tr>");
      }
      out.print("</table></body></html>");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
  }
}
```

content of context.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context crossContext="true">
  <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
  <Resource name="jdbc/testDB" auth="Container"
    type="javax.sql.DataSource"
    maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" 
    username="root" password="root"
    driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/mysql">
</Context>
```

Comment: have you set your username and password of mysql?

Comment: Do you get an error if from localhost you do `mysql -u root -proot` ?

Comment: Most MySQL DBs reject all incoming connections that are not from the same machine as the DB. You can change this, but that requires full access to the DB and because mine is on a shared server I don't have that and don't know how to change it because I knew I couldn't beforehand.

Comment: Note that the error message `Access denied for user ''` doesn't contain the root username. Maybe there is something else going wrong with the context.xml. What tomcat version are you using?

Comment: @user1705985 Actually your problem is in Xml file you have missed Resource tag unclosed.

Answer (score 1):

try connecting to mysql from any other tool / from command prompt with all the information you used in your code to connect to the same. Try including the port also in the connection url. Default port is 3306

Answer (score 1):

Use mysql's `GRANT` query to give you permissions to access the database if you are accessing db from remote client.

Answer (score 0):

seems port number missing in the url:

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:<port>/mysql
```